# how to quick close bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

i use boostrap modal and this

```
<div class="modal fade" onSubmit="return false;" id="a" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg2" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content" style="width:850px; margin:auto">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#a" id="aBtn" type="button">TEST</button>
```

this modal closes slowly when it closes.
maybe animate or fadeOut i presume But I couldn't find a how to modal close quickly

Answer (score 0):

Use Developer tool you will see, when modal show body element will add class 'modal-open', end of body will add a div with class='modal-backdrop show' (in your case class='modal-backdrop fade show'), the modal div will add class 'show'.
My idea is remove them.

```
$('#a').removeClass('show');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop.fade.show').remove();
```